# notifyDataSetChanged not working after i add a dialog to fragment

Tags: android, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a problem updating a list in my fragment. I want the user to enter a text and 2 values from 2 numberpickers. When I use only the AlertDialog, notifyDataSetChanged seems to work fine, and the list is updated when I click the OK button in the AlertDialog.

However, when I add the Dialog with the two numberpickers(after user clicks OK in the AlertDialog) and calling the notifyDataSetChanged nothing happend to the list. I have to close and reopen the fragment in order to upadate.

I have considered refreshing the fragment when the user finishes the adding, but I feel it is not the correct way.

(Any other comment about my code, that can improve it is obviously wellcome!)

```
//add Button
    button2 = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());  //create the AlertBuilder
            alert.setTitle("Subject");
            // Set an EditText view to get user input
            final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    //adds the sub to profile
                    profile.subject.add(input.getText().toString());


                    String[] days = {"Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday" ,"Thursday" ,"Friday"};
                    //dialog with the days
                    final Dialog d = new Dialog(getContext());
                    d.setTitle("Day");
                    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                    Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                    final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
                    final NumberPicker np2 = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
                    np.setMaxValue(4);
                    np.setMinValue(0);
                    np.setDisplayedValues(days);
                    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
                    np2.setMaxValue(4);
                    np2.setMinValue(0);
                    np2.setDisplayedValues(days);
                    np2.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
                    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            profile.day.add(np.getValue());
                            profile.day2.add(np2.getValue());   //add the two values in profile

                            //saves profile
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            String json1 = gson.toJson(profile);
                            editor.putString("DATES" , json1);
                            editor.apply();

                            d.dismiss();

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //should update the list, but instead does nothing
                        }
                    });
                    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    d.show();

                    create(input.getText().toString());
                }

            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Could we see the entire method, including where you setup the adapter and everything? Including the notifyDatasetChanged that actually works

Comment: the notifyDataSetChanged that works is the same thing without the dialog(from String[] days   to   d.show(); )

Comment: ` final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, math);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
`